# How to efficiently apply correction to a time series with fully vectorized code in Matlab

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop, vectorization

I face a computation efficiency problem. I have a time series of a non-monotonically drifting variable, that is measurements of objects going through a machine (where the measurement is made) in a production line. The job to do consists of simulating what this time series would yield if there was a correction made to the object each time the measurement drifts above or below a threshold.

To do that I could simply make a `for` loop, and each time the thresholds are crossed, I apply the correction to the rest of the time series. However the time series is very long and the `for` loop take too much time to compute. I would like to vectorize this code to make it more efficient. Does anyone sees a way to do so?

Here is a working example using a `for` loop:

```
ts = [1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3];
threshold = [-3.5 3];
correction = [1 -1];
for i = 1:numel(ts)
    if ts(i) > threshold(2)
       ts(i:end) = ts(i:end) + correction(2);
   elseif ts(i) < threshold(1)
       ts(i:end) = ts(i:end) + correction(1);
   end
end
disp(ts)
```

The result is and should be the following array:

```
[1 2 3 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -3]
```

How can I vectorize this problem?

Comment: You should use a mask of booleans to filer out data points not satisfying a condition.

Comment: There is no code to debug here. The question is what is the best algorithmic strategy to do the job (other than a simple for loop). There is no point in creating a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example".

Comment: Thanks  MLguy for you comment. The problem is that I apply one correction at a time and one correction affect the rest of the time serie, Thus before making the correction, the second point that do not satisfy the condition might satisfy it after implementing the correction to correcte the first point. So the boolean mask would be relevant only for the first correction. So we fall back to the for loop strategy.

Comment: Questions about improving *working* code are off-topic at Stack Overflow, they *may be* on-topic at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I removed the [python] tag from your question as the question now contains MATLAB code; I voted to reopen.

Comment: @GertArnold the first half of your statement is incorrect. Just because existing code is not buggy doesn't mean the question is off-topic here. [See also](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: @AndrasDeak OK, maybe I should have worded it differently, but I don't see how a question asking "more efficient way to compute this kind of task" isn't "too broad" here. Do you think it's off-topic at CR? If not we (SO users) may need to give OP some advice on how to make it on-topic here.

Comment: @GertArnold I only said that it's not _off-topic_. It can easily be too broad, but that's a different matter. It might be on topic on CR as you said, but 1. the scope of the question is somewhat localized, and 2. I'm not familiar with the norms on CR to judge anyway. A general question of "how do I do this better" is usually too broad. [Vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vectorization), on the other hand, is a very specific approach to optimizing loops, which is a fundamental tool in certain high-level languages such as MATLAB or python+numpy.

Comment: @GertArnold & AndrasDeak. To make the post a bit less off-topic I clarified the question (and narrowed the scope of solutions) by specifically asking about vectorization in matlab. I will try to post it on CR as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Gert Arnold FYI, I posted that question on CR and it is off topic as well (I got "we review the code you have, not the code you want to have."). Fair enough. Tricky question that is mine, I guess. May be I should open a web site for posting question like this: "How to improve my code performance". It's a very interesting topic I think... Thanks you anyway guys :).